# Smooth Background Color Transition with smoothstate.js

Tags: javascript, background-color, smoothstate.js

I would like to change the background color of each page in a smooth way with smoothstate.js

How can I do this? I've tried to add the style-css in the header of each page but it doesn't work.

For example a smooth background color transition on this page: http://miguel-perez.github.io/smoothState.js/demos/typical/

Page 1

```
body{background-color: red;}
```

Page 2

```
body{background-color: green;}
```

Comment: Have you done all of the steps in the Getting Started section? Have you run $('#main').smoothState()? https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js#getting-started

Comment: Yes, I used the original code from here: http://miguel-perez.github.io/smoothState.js/demos/typical/functions.js